# American persimmon - identification

Tags: identification, persimmon, american

I'm located in Europe and that trees are not very common here. Can you confirm that's really persimon trees? That's how they look after 3 years:
[image]
[image]

Can you confirm it's really american persimmon trees? I planted them 3 years ago, now they are more than 2 meters tall and still no flowers or fruits present. I'm not sure it's really american persimon, as they look somehow different from the images on the net